# SignalR with unreliable or paused & reconnected connections?

Tags: signalr

I'm considering updating an existing site to use SignalR. My site polls a third party service for data changes, does some magic on it, and clients poll it once every few minutes to refresh their view with any updates.

SignalR seems like a great way to eliminate the polling from the client, but I want to know how SignalR handles dropped & reconnected connections, especially with regards to mobile web apps which may have been suspended for some time. Will it automatically negotiate and queue up any updates that were missed in the meantime, or does the client need to resynch from scratch in these cases? I looked but couldn't find any docs on this so guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All this is definitely possible since the client keeps track of the last message id it saw. If it happened to miss messages, it'll get those the next time it goes back to the server (asking for all messages since the last one it saw).

By default the server side of SignalR stores messages in memory (and it purges those every few  seconds), but you can change it to persist to some persistent store (see [IMessageStore](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/SignalR/IMessageStore.cs)) if you're thinking about clients going offline and catching up.

You could even persist messages yourself in your own app logic while SignalR stores stuff in memory. It really depends on the application.

We haven't added any special support for mobile clients, but you can persist the message id in whatever local storage you need to for your mobile client.

Those details aren't very specific but what you want to do is all possible with SignalR.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Extra credit: can you point me to any demo apps/code that do something like this?

Comment: No I cannot :). SignalR is brand new and we haven't done much work with mobile devices as yet.

Comment: Ah well. The fact that it's mobile isn't directly relevant, but it's one where you can **count on** interruptions from the network (_*cough* AT&T_), the app suspending/terminating without warning, etc. It sounds like it has the low-level hooks necessary - IDs in requests, IMessageStore - to build the rest on top myself. Will share if I can genericize it sufficiently!

Comment: Did you ever make a simple generic app for this? I'm doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Understanding and Handling Connection Lifetime Events in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events), especially these sections:

- [How to continuously reconnect](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#continuousreconnect) - required to recover from a disconnected state;
- [How to notify the user about disconnections](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#notifydisconnect) - so your app can not only inform the user, but detect state changes (disconnected, reconnecting, reconnected) to refresh your app's state in other ways.

That document was written in 2014 and basically obsoletes many of the wrong or incomplete StackOverflow SignalR-related questions/answers from the 2011-2012 era.